# media player error codes

Tags: android, media-player, error-code

This [link](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/external/opencore.git;a=blob;f=pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h;h=ed5a2539ca85ae60425229be41646b6bd7d9389c;hb=HEAD) is broken. Are there any other resource that keeps media player error codes?

or does anybody know what the -18 error code means?

Thanks,

Comment: please past your code and error here

Comment: My question is not about the problem in my code. I just want to know what -18 error code means? It is a straightforward videoview approach. Videos are played in most devices, but samsung i5510 gives this error(-18). All error codes were defined in the link above, however it is broken now.

Comment: Both the android kernel and android moved to github when kernel.org went down. Android might even be staying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h

```
/*
 Error due to general data processing
 */
const PVMFStatus PVMFErrProcessing = (-18);
```